# Tracking down DFS open file users

Tags: windows-server-2008, dfs

I have a file in a DFS share, it's in a namespace managed by two domain controllers
The base media is one shared drive on a file server
I can't delete it, it keeps re-appearing
when I run sysinternals handle utility on the file server it tells me the file is opened by PID 4, which appears to be 'system'

I assume thats the DFS service or sharing service that's actually doing the sharing.

How can I determine who is has the file open and from where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DFS service simply maps the correct folder to the correct location, I can't imagine it would maintain a file handle on anything. What is the name of the file that keeps appearing? Right click the file, go properties -> Details and find out who created the file, that's probably your culprit. As far as checking which Users have which file open, I don't know if it's possible on a windows server machine, but this thread might help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581219/find-out-who-is-locking-a-file-on-a-network-share

Comment: Thanks!   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/581219/find-out-who-is-locking-a-file-on-a-network-share was the key.